# Derivation of a very general form of Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

For the following derivation of a general Euler-Lagrange equation I understand the $E_{\gamma}$ part but have trouble figuring out where the $W^i[u,v]$ part is coming from.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The book mentions that boundary conditions are arbitrary but I still do not see how they are in the form of $W^i$.